# How to trigger stages on file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a Jenkins pipeline. I am looking for trick to trigger pipeline stages when one JSON file exists in path.

Comment: Did you check the pipeline steps reference and/or snippet generator? You may want to check for the `fileExists` step.

Comment: if you want to trigger that when specific JSON file is in changeset then check https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when 'changeset' section